# Number of ways to pick out pairs of balls from an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics, polya-urn-model

We have an urn with $2N$ balls, of four colors $(a,b,c,d)$. I want to know how many ways there are to pick *pairs* of balls until the urn is empty. Note that $(x,y)$ pair is equivalent to $(y,x)$. Also see [Mark Fischler's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338518/number-of-ways-to-pick-out-pairs-of-balls-from-an-urn#comment6871040_3338518) below for additional equivalences.

For example, we have an urn with $(0, 2, 0, 8)$ balls, $2N=10$.

First, we can pick a pair $(b,b)$, leaving us with $(0,0,0,8)$. Now we can only take $(d,d)$ pairs four times until the urn is empty. This sequence of moves leads to the outcome $1\times(b,b), 4\times(d,d)$.

Alternatively, we can pick $(b,d)$, leaving us with $(0,1,0,7)$. Now we have to pick another $(b,d)$ pair (since the leftover $b$ has to be picked eventually), leading to $(0,0,0,6)$. We empty the urn by taking $(d,d)$ three more times. This sequence leads to $2\times(b,d), 3\times(d,d)$.

Thus, starting from $(0,2,0,8)$, we have the following possible pair selections:

\begin{aligned}
1\times&(b,b)\\
2\times&(b,d)\\
(4+3)\times&(d,d)
\end{aligned}

Is there a name for this selection scheme? Is there a closed for solution for this? The best I was able to come up with so far has been an iterative algorithm that generates all the possible pair selections, and then [counts them up](https://gist.github.com/ivan-krukov/238d3f5c2b52846c1e6157da1305e0bb).

Comment: You should clarify by stating that two sequences of 1-ball picks are considered equivalent if for each $k\in[1,N]$ either the $k$-th balls are equal in the and the $k+1$-st balls are equal in the two sequences, or ball $k$ in sequence A matches ball $k+1$ in sequence B and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the answer in what could be considered "closed form"!

First some notation, following that in Concrete Mathematics: Let $P(a, b, \ldots , z)$ be some polynomial in $\{a, b, \ldots , z)\}$.  Then
$$
[a^\alpha b^\beta \cdots z^\omega] P
$$
means the coefficient in $P$ of the term $[a^\alpha b^\beta \cdots z^\omega]$.  For example, 
$$
[x^2y^4](x^2+x y + y^2)^3  = 6
$$ 
because $(x^2+x y + y^2)^3 = \mathbf{6}x^2 y^4 + 6 y^2 x^4 + x^6 + y^6 + 3 x^5 y + 3 y^5 x + 7x^3 y^3$.

Consider an urn with $2N$ balls of $C$ colors, and say that for each value of color $c$ the urn containing $n_c$ balls.

(In your case, there are $2N$ balls, choosing among $4$ colors, so $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 2N$.)

Let $Q(x_1, x_2, \ldots ,x_C)$ be the most general homogeneous quadratic polynomial with unit coefficients:
$$
Q(x_1,  x_2, \ldots ,x_C) = \sum_i x_i^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j
$$
where the indices $i$ and $j$ range from $1$ to $C$.  In your 4 color example,
$$
Q(x_1,  x_2, x_3 ,x_4) = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 +x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)
$$
Then the number of distinct ways to choose a sequence of pairs from those balls is given by

> $$
> [x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} \cdots x_C^{n_C}]\,\,Q^N
> $$

As an example, say there are $5$ red balls, $3$ blue balls, $6$ green balls and $8$ yellow balls.  $N = 11$ in that case. Then there will be 
$$
[x^5y^3z^6w^8]\,\,  (x^2 + y^2+ z^2 + w^2 + xy+xz+xw+yz+yw+zw) ^{11}= 281953980
$$
ways to draw the 11 pairs.

Doing this with explicit recursion would take forever; using this polynomial expansion it is instantaneous in Mathematica and even plausible by hand.

You can see why this works, since each contribution to $Q^N$ selects $N$ pairs in some order and needs to consume each of the colors in exactly the right numbers.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, thank you! Upon further pondering, I think my original question was "how many ways are there to pick a particular pair, say ($zw$)", but I suppose that is not what I asked in the question above. Your solution takes moments in Mathematica (`Coefficient[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 + x y + x z + x w + y z + y w + 
   z w)^11, x^5 y^3 z^6 w^8]`)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know how many, you can make a recurrence.  Let $A,B,C,D$ be the number of balls of each color.  Then
$$f(A,B,C,D)=f(A-2,B,C,D)+f(A-1,B-1,C,D)+\ldots$$
all the other similar terms.  The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to generate all the different orders.  This suggests a recursive algorithm in your favorite language.  I doubt it will be easy to get a closed form.

Comment: But solving that recurrence in closed form won't be easy.

Comment: @MarkFischler:  Agreed and added.